# How can I solve json.decoder.JSONDecodeError(python)?

Tags: python, json, twitter, web-crawler

twitter keywords crawling python

An error occurred."json.decoder.JSONDecodeError"

As a beginner, I don't know about json.decoder.JSONDecodeError  (T.T)

So I searched the Internet.

Installed on the Internet to install " Jsonrpclib " and " simplejson ".

Do I have to modify the code?

```
import tweepy
import time
import os
import json
import simplejson

search_term = 'word1'
search_term2= 'word2'
search_term3='word3'

lat = "xxxx"
lon = "xxxx"
radius = "xxxx"
location = "%s,%s,%s" % (lat, lon, radius)

API_key = "xxxx"
API_secret = "xxxx"
Access_token = "xxxx"
Access_token_secret = "xxxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_key, API_secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access_token, Access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

c=tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                q="{}+OR+{}".format(search_term, search_term2, search_term3),
                rpp=1000,
                geocode=location,
                include_entities=True)

data = {}
i = 1
for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)

wfile = open(os.getcwd()+"/workk2.txt", mode='w')   
data = {}   
i = 0       

for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text   
    wfile.write(data['text']+'\n')  
    i += 1


wfile.close()
```

Comment: Please don't install unnecessary packages, python has a `json` library that works like charm

Comment: have a package, but why is there an error?
However, when I entered the pip list in cmd, I installed it because it was not installed.

Comment: You don't need to install it, it comes with the python

Comment: aha! If it's installed, won't the error occur?
Also, Is there any need to modify the code above?